# Passing data from form 1 to form 2 in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

This is the first part of my code, I didn't include all of the button clicks and methods so it wouldn't be as long. The comments included in the code are instructions from my professor.

When I initialize the ScoresDisplay array in wndTestScores and use the showDialog the values are reset once the wndDisplayScores is opened. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Please go easy on me, I'm very new to C#.

```
 public partial class wndTestScores : Window
 {
        public static int[] scores = new int[21];
        public static int amountOfScores = 1;

    public wndTestScores()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

  


    private void btnAsEntered_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create an instance of the WPF window wndDisplayScores
        wndDisplayScores displayScores = new wndDisplayScores();


        //Code a for statement to loop through each array
        //element of your integer array of test scores. If the
        //test score in your array element is greater than 0 then
        //set ScoresDisplay array element to your array element value.
        //The ScoresDisplay is a public array on the DisplayScores
        //window.
        for(int x = 1; x < amountOfScores; x++)
        {
            if (scores[x] > 0)
                displayScores.ScoresDisplay[x] = scores[x];
        }

        //Display the DisplayScores window by calling the ShowDialog()
        //method


        displayScores.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void BtnAddScore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int score;
        bool valid = false;

        if(amountOfScores > 20)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Max amount of test scores entered. Please select another option.");
            return;
        }
        
        Int32.TryParse(txtTestScore.Text, out score);

        if (Int32.TryParse(txtTestScore.Text, out score) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input try again.");
            txtTestScore.Clear();
        }
        
        valid = isValid(valid, score);

        if (valid == true)
        {
            scores[amountOfScores] = score;
            amountOfScores++;
        }


        if(amountOfScores > 2)
        {
            rdoAverage.IsEnabled = true;
            rdoHighest.IsEnabled = true;
            rdoLowest.IsEnabled = true;
            rdoMedian.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        
    }
}
```

'''

```
public partial class wndDisplayScores : Window
{
    public int[] ScoresDisplay = new int[21];

    public wndDisplayScores()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load_TestScores();

    }
    private void Load_TestScores()
    {
        //Code a foreach statement that will iterate
        //through the array ScoresDisplay. If the array 
        //element contains a test score greater than 0
        //then add the test score to the ListBox control
        foreach(int x in ScoresDisplay)
        {
            if (x > 0)
                lstScores.Items.Add(x);
        }

    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean to say that lstScores in your wndDisplayScores form is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that lstScores collection in wndDisplayScores form is empty.

The reason is pretty straight forward:

```
private void btnAsEntered_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    LINE 1: wndDisplayScores displayScores = new wndDisplayScores();

    LINE 2: for(int x = 1; x < amountOfScores; x++)
    {
        if (scores[x] > 0)
            displayScores.ScoresDisplay[x] = scores[x];
    }

    LINE 3: displayScores.ShowDialog();

}
```

In this method, you first create an instance of second form at LINE 1, which calls its constructor right away. In the constructor of wndDisplayScores - you have a call to Load_TestScores();

This runs right away and at this time there is nothing in "public int[] ScoresDisplay = new int[21];" member. Because that will happen in forloop LINE 2 after wards.

Comment: I ended up adding a Loaded event to wndDisplayScores and called Load_TestScores() from there instead. Now it works how I wanted to, thank you for explaing where I went wrong!